# android LocationClient how to set time out?

Tags: android, location, location-client

I am working on an app that require to obtain the user's current location. I had googling a lot, it seems that the LocationClient have no option to set the time out value. **If I disabled the google location service and no GPS signal, it keep connecting.** Is there a way to set the timeout? When the connection time exceed certain value, display "time out".

Thanks!